# Run parallel tasks in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to run all playbooks generated under included task module dynamically in parallel not one after another.

```yaml
- name: Include tasks
  include_tasks: {{ item.app_type }}.yml
  with_items: "{{xyz}}"
```

The above task generates 20 scripts.yml and runs them one after another but I want to run all in parallel.

Comment: Please make this a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve). You'll also want to read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html